Grease pencil line art lofi effects
I’m trying to find new ways to add some artificial imperfections to my lineart in grease pencil. Something along the lines of chromatic abbhoration, or smudgeyness, almost like a photoshop Burn overlay effect. It would be cool to see some random automated color and grain artifacts in my linework. I’ve seen this done in many bodies of work but didn’t know if grease pencil has any capabilities like this outside of adding a material texture. Does anything like this exist? I’ve added an example of this artist who uses some really cool materials !! It looks like they have some sort of paintbrush add on or something. Any ideas ? Working on a project that needs this type of mastering


Hi Toctac, it'd be more appreciated if you were to ask for something specific. What is the exact effect you want? Do you have an image of what it would look like?

Hey! I just updated my post with image examples

Chromatic aberration is something that happens with lenses, not paint. Regardless, I think your best shot at this is something in the compositor, but it depends on if you just want to render grease pencil or there’s something else in the scene.

Oh interesting! I didn’t even know you could use the compositor for grease pencil! I thought it was only for 3d objects. So much to learn!

Could you possibly suggest some resources where I could learn about how to use compositors in this way? The things I’m finding online aren’t really helping that much
